# Tomcat 8 and Grails deploying war loop

Tags: java, tomcat, grails, deployment

I have Tomcat 8.0.23 running and I am able to run their sample war files so that means I can run war files. Now the issue happens when I try to deploy my grails app. What I do is this:

I want to make sure that a grails app (2.5.0) just runs fine as a war file on Tomcat 8.
So I create a grails app, I do NOT change anything, and I then create the war file as `grails war`. I take the file from the target folder and I put it under webapps in my Tomcat. It is not loading. This is what I get:

```
26-Jun-2015 20:34:43.373 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
26-Jun-2015 20:34:43.378 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.23
26-Jun-2015 20:34:43.454 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive /opt/tomcat/webapps/sample.war
26-Jun-2015 20:34:44.414 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive /opt/tomcat/webapps/sample.war has finished in 953 ms
26-Jun-2015 20:34:44.416 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive /opt/tomcat/webapps/example.war
26-Jun-2015 20:34:50.485 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.23
26-Jun-2015 20:34:50.487 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          May 19 2015 14:58:38 UTC
26-Jun-2015 20:34:50.488 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.23.0
26-Jun-2015 20:34:50.489 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
26-Jun-2015 20:34:50.489 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            3.13.0-52-generic
26-Jun-2015 20:34:50.490 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
26-Jun-2015 20:34:50.490 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
26-Jun-2015 20:34:50.490 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.7.0_79-b14
26-Jun-2015 20:34:50.491 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
26-Jun-2015 20:34:50.491 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /opt/tomcat
26-Jun-2015 20:34:50.492 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /opt/tomcat
26-Jun-2015 20:34:50.492 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
26-Jun-2015 20:34:50.493 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
26-Jun-2015 20:34:50.493 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.awt.headless=true
26-Jun-2015 20:34:50.494 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom
26-Jun-2015 20:34:50.494 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xms512M
26-Jun-2015 20:34:50.494 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx1024M
26-Jun-2015 20:34:50.495 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:+UseParallelGC
26-Jun-2015 20:34:50.495 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/tomcat/endorsed
26-Jun-2015 20:34:50.496 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/opt/tomcat
26-Jun-2015 20:34:50.496 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat
26-Jun-2015 20:34:50.496 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tomcat/temp
26-Jun-2015 20:34:50.497 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
26-Jun-2015 20:34:50.695 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
26-Jun-2015 20:34:50.767 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
26-Jun-2015 20:34:50.778 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
26-Jun-2015 20:34:50.781 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
26-Jun-2015 20:34:50.786 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 1410 ms
26-Jun-2015 20:34:50.853 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
26-Jun-2015 20:34:50.858 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.23
26-Jun-2015 20:34:50.934 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive /opt/tomcat/webapps/sample.war
26-Jun-2015 20:34:51.935 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive /opt/tomcat/webapps/sample.war has finished in 997 ms
26-Jun-2015 20:34:51.943 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive /opt/tomcat/webapps/example.war
```

This keeps lopping over and over again. I can deploy `sample` but it gets stuck at  the grails one "example".

Why ? I have set the autodeploy to false if that helps. (I am hosting on Digital Ocean on the 512mb ram machine)

Thanks

Comment: did you ever figure this out?